# os.system Linux translation

Tags: python, gurobi, pulp

I'm working on a MILP problem written in python (using pulp and gurobi). 
Obviously the original developer used Windows and I am running the code on Ubuntu. I am new to this and there is this piece of the code that I really don't understand.

```
    "FOR WINDOWS: Catch infeasible model and compute the IIS: to capture the infeasibility source"
    if  MILP.status == pulp.constants.LpStatusInfeasible:
        print 'Model Infeasible catched in i='+str(i)+''
        #'remove all the existing .mps'
        os.system('"del '+str('*.mps')+'"')
        #'create the .mps being transformed in .ilp'
        MILP.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD())
        MPS_file_created = glob.glob("*.mps")
        #'transform the .mps into a .ilp'
        os.system('"C:\gurobi600\gurobi600\win64'+str(r'\bin')+'\gurobi_cl.exe ResultFile=violated_constraint.ilp '
                  +MPS_file_created[0]+'"')
        print HEMS_MILP
```

I would like to know if this influences the solution and if so - how to use this method in ubuntu.

Comment: Doesn't anyone understand this?

Comment: If I was going to do this I would just convert the whole program to use the gurobi python api, then deal with it like that.